# CPU as default for tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I want to use the CPU as default. Only some code should be given to the GPU using `tf.device("/gpu:0"):`.

When I use

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
```

tensorflow will still use my GPU.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58845/how-to-disable-gpu-with-tensorflow) Make sure you call that before anything related to tensorflow is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using both `tf.device('/CPU:0')` and `tf.device('/GPU:0')`. Please find the sample code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
 a=tf.constant([[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0]])
 b=tf.constant([[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0],[5.0,6.0]])
 d=tf.matmul(a,b) 
 print(d)

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
  c=tf.matmul(a,b)
  print(c)
```

Output:

```
Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
Executing op MatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```